# How to find a verification routine that enables a button and a textbox

Tags: crackme

I have an app (reverseme) that looks like calc.exe.
It has 9 number btns, clear and enter buttons.
The enter is disabled.

There is another input textbox without any enter or submit button. It takes inlut from the keyboard but when i press enter it doesnt throw any badboy or goodboy messages just a sound of a bad press.

I need to enable the enter button and find the serial.

The app compiled with borland and writteb in c++.
It uses kernel32, user32, comctc32.

I have disabled the entered button by enabling it in reseditor and noping the disabling routine in the code but im shure there is another way.

Comment: Set the breakpoints described in [Find a string that I entered in ollydbg](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2796/find-a-string-that-i-entered-in-ollydbg) to find the verification routine.

Comment: The input is not submited because the enter and the textbox are disabled

Comment: So you set breakpoints on `GetWindowText()`, `GetDlgItemText()`, `SendMessage()`, etc. and saw none of the breakpoints hit while entering content into the textbox?

Comment: A small screenshot might help. Additionally, the app may handle the [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx) within the message loop. You need to check that too.

Comment: [Also related question.](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8929/use-ollydbg-to-identify-what-happens-when-a-button-is-pressed/8932#8932)

Comment: Jason There is no reference of GetDigItem. I found the creation of the window when i set a bp on EnableWindow. And i found the decision making call that enables or disables the enter. I set a hw bp on write on the decision pointer but didn't found anything interesting